# Pagination won't bring content, pages are showing but empty

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following code, The current page is showing content.But when i click first or next page nothing is showing even the footer disappears. my database has category table and products table, Im getting data by category id. If i remove where clause, it prints out all products.   What am i missing? please help.

this is the error i get

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php on line 36 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php(47): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php on line 47

```
<?php
    
      $slug = $_GET['category'];
    
      $conn = $pdo->open();
    
      try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_slug = :slug");
        $stmt->execute(['slug' => $slug]);
        $cat = $stmt->fetch();
        $catid = $cat['id'];
      }
      catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
    
      $pdo->close();
    
 
    //--------------Html code here-------//

                     $limit = 12;
                    $conn = $pdo->open();
                     $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id =  $catid");
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // echo '<pre>';
        // var_dump($result);
        $total_results = $sql->rowCount();
        $total_pages = ceil($total_results/$limit);
        
        if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = 1;
        } else{
            $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page']);
        }
    
    
        $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
                    
                    try{
      
                      $inc = 3; 
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = :catid LIMIT $start, $limit");
                    $stmt->execute(['catid' => $catid]);
                    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
      
                      $image = (!empty($row['photo'])) ? 'images/'.$row['photo'] : 'images/noimage.jpg';
                      $inc = ($inc == 3) ? 1 : $inc + 1;
                        if($inc == 1) echo "<div class='row'>";
                        echo "
                          <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class='box box-solid'>
                              <div class='box-body prod-body'>
                                <img src='".$image."' width='240px' height='230px' class='thumbnail'>
                                <a href='product.php?product=".$row['slug']."'>".$row['name']."</a><hr>
                                </div>
                                <div class='box-footer'>
                                <span><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> ".$row['suburb_province']." &nbsp; &#124;  &nbsp;&nbsp;<small>Posted &#8208; <strong>". date('M d, Y',strtotime($row['date_view']))."</strong></small> </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class='box-footer'>
                                <b>R ".number_format($row['price'], 2)."</b><br></b><br>
                              </div>
    
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ";
                        if($inc == 3) echo "</div>";
                    }
                    if($inc == 1) echo "<div class='col-sm-4'></div><div class='col-sm-4'></div></div>"; 
                  if($inc == 2) echo "<div class='col-sm-4'></div></div>";
                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                  echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
                }
    
                $pdo->close();
                    // var_dump($stmt);
    
                 $no = $page > 1 ? $start+1 : 1;
                  $no++; 
                  ?><hr>
                     <ul class="pagination">
            <?php echo "<li><a href='category.php?category=".$slug."?page=1'>First</a></li>";?>
            
           <?php for($p=1; $p<=$total_pages; $p++){?>
                
                <li class="<?= $page == $p ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?= '?page='.$p; ?>"><?= $p; ?></a></li>
            <?php }?>
           <?php echo "<li><a href='category.php?category=".$slug."?page= $total_pages'>Last</a></li>"; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: What's happening in the background? Are there errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right place holder

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_slug = :slug");
    $stmt->execute([':slug'=> $slug]);
    $cat = $stmt->fetch();
    $catid = $cat['id'];
```

see example fiddle https://phpize.online/?phpses=cce56c52d932221dbb2f0ddf71f363e2&sqlses=e561f2b99e243548e745f04491c22dd6&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: So in category table i have column "cat_slug" and in products i have "category_id" which takes its value from cat_slug. so i really don't know how to add that pagination. Without it the code it working fine. But when i add pagination and limit pages, it doesnt bring content. changing place holeder give me the same problem

Comment: @the_guru  please see the example that it works just fine,

Comment: so i have changed the code to "  $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM category LEFT JOIN products ON products.category_id=category.id WHERE cat_slug = :slug");
                          $stmt2->execute(['slug'=>$slug]);
                           $allResp = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); " and the error has changed to Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php on line 37 that error code is: <?php echo $cat['name']; ?> and $catid = $cat['id']; How do i get rid of this error?

Comment: you didn't read  my answer `slug` must be `:slug` see the working example link feel free to edit it and and add more tables.  and code

Comment: I did read your comment, i added  :slug and im getting "Warning: Undefined array key "category" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php on line 5"Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ecommerce/category.php on line 11"  i then added the following on line 11 "if ($cat) { $catid = $cat['id'];}" i get a different error. But if i use left Join its only getting one category and pagination is working

Comment: you chaged again your code. please accept the answer, as it answers your question and ask a new question with the actual code, you got now.